# Como faço para animar um objeto no canvas com um bind com uma animação já "rodando"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Eu estava fazendo um jogo copia de **Space Invaders** mas quando fui fazer o "tiro"
da nave, me deparei com um seguinte problema :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como visto no Gif, ao eu apertar a tecla, tudo que esta no canvas "congela" até o tiro chegar ao final, como faço para resolver isso ? desde já, agradeço.

Trecho do código :

```
def Update (self):
    while True :
        self.Move_nave()
        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(30)

def Shot (self, event):
    self.a_0 , self.a_2 = int(self.c.coords (self.bola)[0]), int(self.c.coords (self.bola)[2])
    self.a_1, self.a_3 = int (self.c.coords(self.bola)[1]), int (self.c.coords(self.bola)[3])
    self.tiro = self.c.create_rectangle(self.a_0 + 10, self.a_1, self.a_2 - 10, self.a_3, fill = 'blue')
    for c in range (10):
        self.c.move(self.tiro, 0, -10)
        self.root.after(40)
        self.root.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: O problema tem a ver com o `for` dentro do método `Shot`, que não pode ser feito dessa forma para atualizar o tiro. Em vez disso tem de ter uma lista de tiros existentes e ir atualizando um a um em cada frame. O ideal no entanto é fornecer um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema, para que seja fácil mostrar a solução.

Comment: Mas ainda sim, como eu irei usar dois "afters" ao mesmo tempo ?

Comment: Teria apenas um `after` para cada atualização dos vários componentes

Comment: Mas sem o **after** do **shot** ele não ira animar o tiro e simplesmente aparecera ao eu apertar a tecla.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa de uma reformulação no seu código.

Ao disparar o tiro, você não pode animar o tiro completamente até ao fim. Ao invés disso, deve criar um objeto que armazene a posição do tiro, pode usar uma classe pra isso ou somente uma estrutura simples como uma tupla.

Em seguida você precisa adicionar essa estrutura que representa o tiro a uma lista, pode chamar de `tiros_atuais` que vai conter todos os tiros que estão ativos no momento.

Em um determinado ponto único do seu código, você precisa atualizar todos os elementos do jogo. Atualize a posição da nave e também de todos os tiros que estiverem na lista `tiros_atuais`. Assim você vai ter um `.after()` só no seu código - e ele vai fazer **todas** as atualizações que dependem de tempo de seu jogo.

Finalmente, se o tiro chegou ao destino, remova-o da lista `tiros_atuais` para que ele pare de ser atualizado.

Comment: Você poderia postar o código ? =P

Comment: @Tortaamolante eu não tenho um código. Como seu código está incompleto não pude executá-lo aqui. Além disso essa mudança seria uma reformulação geral para implementar essa lógica diferente. Acredito que a minha resposta está completa e clara o suficiente, respondendo a pergunta de forma integral, sem precisar de código para completá-la. Tente implementar a solução que propus, e, caso tenha problemas, abra uma nova pergunta, mais específica, com o código que tentou escrever seguindo essa lógica.